# camera-service-googlecamera burst 0 info expected not found

Tags: java, google-glass, google-gdk

I am developing a simplest video recording glassware. The app works well in my android phone (DROID X) and Virtual Device, but in Google Glass LogCat says something below. The 2 problems I have now:

1. **no preview. it just gives a black screen**
2. **no output file, or an output file with size ZERO**.

   > 06-17 12:54:24.805: E/CameraService-GoogleCamera(1925): ERROR - Burst 0 info expected, not found
   >
   > 06-17 12:54:24.805: E/BufferQueue(1925): [unnamed-1925-0] setBufferCount: client owns some buffers
   >
   > 06-17 12:54:24.977: A/OMXCodec(1925): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp:4219 CHECK_EQ(
   >   err,(status_t)OK) failed: -2147483648 vs. 0
   >
   > 06-17 12:54:24.977: A/libc(1925): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000785 (code=-6), thread 1961 (Binder_1)
   >
   > 06-17 12:54:25.469: E/AudioService(514): Media server died.
   >
   > 06-17 12:54:25.969: E/AudioService(514): Media server started.

The code is as below

```
package edu.ds.cameracontrolandroid;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import edu.ds.cameracontrolandroid.R;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

    public static final String LOGTAG = "DS";

    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;


    boolean recording = false;


    private String filename = "";

    private boolean recordClosed = false;

    SurfaceView cameraView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG,"external storage not writable");
            }


        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);

        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        Handler handler=new Handler();
        Runnable r=new Runnable(){
            public void run() {

                Log.e(LOGTAG,"runnable");
                finish();               
            }   
        }; 
        handler.postDelayed(r, 15000);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "surfaceChanged");


        recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface()); 

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT); 
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT); 

        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

        recorder.setMaxDuration(1000 * 15); 
        //recorder.setOnInfoListener(self); 

        //Camera camera = Camera.open();
        //Size size = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);

        //recorder.setVideoSize(size.width, size.height);

        recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);


         try {
             File newFile = File.createTempFile("videocapture", ".mp4", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM));
             //File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"DCIM/Camera");


             //recorder.setOutputFile(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
             filename = newFile.getAbsolutePath();
             Log.e(LOGTAG, "file -- " + filename);
             recorder.setOutputFile(filename);
         } 
         catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(LOGTAG, "Couldn't create file -- " + filename);
             e.printStackTrace();
             finish();

             return;
         }

        try {
            recorder.prepare(); 
            recorder.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "prepare --"  + e.toString()); **//There is no error message printed out here!!!**
            finish();
        }

    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "surfaceDestroyed");

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish(){

        if(recordClosed) return;
            try{

                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();

                Log.e(LOGTAG,"stopping");                           

                recordClosed = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


}
```